# Python Pydantic with Variables (Literal, ==, eq=)

Tags: python, factory, pydantic

How can I use pydantic to require that my object has an exact numeric value set by a variable?

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

var = 10.0

class Group(BaseModel):
     value: Literal[var] # something like this
     value: float = Field(..., eq=var) # or this
```

Furthermore, what is the best way to create `pydantic` classes that use variables? Is there a way to do it within the class (instead of factory) so that the same class can be used to validate against different values?

```py
from typing import Literal, TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

TGroup = TypeVar("TGroup", bound="Group") # does not work

def factory(var: float) -> TGroup: 
    class Group(BaseModel):
        value: Literal[var]
    return Group

# instead do something like this
class Group(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, var: float, **data) -> None:
        self.value: str = Field(..., regex=f'{var}')
        super().__init__(**data)

obj = {'value': 10}
Group(var=10, **obj) # does not work
```

Comment: use TypeVar check this for other options https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/

Comment: @deadshot TY for the help! The above does not seem to work. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `validator` to validate the value that is passed.

Here's what your code could look like. Though, I have a doubt about the two variables with the same name...

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, validator

val: float = 10.0

class Group(BaseModel):
     # Are you sure you can have to variables with the same name?
     value: Literal[var] # something like this
     value: float

    @validator('value')
    def check_value(cls, v):
        if v == val:
            return v

        raise ValueError(f'Value must be equal to {val}')
```

And here the official docs

https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/

Comment: Thanks @Isabi. I'd then have to use a `factory()` function to create the class to instantiate the Group with different `val` values right? Or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Do you mean to dynamically set the `val` for the condition? To be honest I don't know well. I guess it would work, but I don't understand the context. Maybe providing an extra field with the context and dynamically retrieving the `val` for that context could be an option?